# Getting System.OutOfMemoryExceptionin returning json data in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

I have tried following code in ASP.NET MVC

```
DBEntities dbEntity = new DBEntities();
        StudentModel stdsearch = new StudentModel();
        var students = (from std in dbEntity.STUDENT
                       select std).ToList();// Returns around 400 rows
// Tried following code for json error
        var jsonResult = Json(students, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
        return jsonResult;
```

Now i am getting out of memory exception

I have also cleared temp data.Also tried the following code

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer { MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue, RecursionLimit = 100 };
        return new ContentResult()
        {
            Content = serializer.Serialize(students),
            ContentType = "application/json",
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the circular reference.
If you want to convert "STUDENT" model alone not an other reference model.
Set LazyLoading true to DBContext

Ex:

> context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your application as 64 bit. If it is 32 bit then you will have low memory.